# How to mention an amendment to the U.S. Constitution in text in APA style

Tags: thesis, citation-style

In the dissertation, several amendments are mentioned in a general way. Do you spell out the amendment numbers or not or does it matter?

- Justice Douglas addressed the Eighth Amendment and the Fourteenth Amendment ...
- Justice Douglas addressed the 8th Amendment and the 14th Amendment ...

The university handbook is silent on the matter, so APA style prevails. I looked in the APA 6th edition, which shows examples for in-text citations and for reference entries. But could not find any examples of a general nature.

I also do not have access to the Legal Bluebook.

Answer (score 4):

Received an answer at the APA style blog:

Regular number formatting applies when an amendment is mentioned as part of a sentence: spell out for the first through ninth amendments and use numerals thereafter
(e.g., “the fourth amendment,” “the 12th amendment”).

http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/06/how-to-cite-the-us-constitution-in-apa-style.html